# Set Ansible environment in play for playbooks

Tags: ansible

I know *environment* can be used to set env. but the maximum scope it covers seems just within the play where it is set (doc says so). I want to set env for a set of playbooks that included together and executed in sequence.

If I do CLI shell command *export MYVAR=myvalue*, playbooks will pick it up and work properly.
But I need playbooks being able to change the value during execution. So on localhost scope, I tried

```
- shell: export MYVAR=myvalue2
```

It executed fine but no other playbooks that ran later able to see it.

Is there a way to set env for Ansible just like I do from system CLI?

Comment: What is the goal here?  What is going to use this environment variable?

Comment: @Jack, change ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH for different playbooks.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html depends your's needs.You can use hostvars too, and other playbook can able to see it.

Comment: @Gary521 You're running this via command line, so just wrap the thing in a bash script and set `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH` as you need to in there.

Comment: @Jack I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. I believe that did the same as doing as a command -- was set in the current task shell. Once the task is finished, it's gone.

Comment: Do you want it set on the host running the `ansible-playbook` command, or set on the managed hosts?

Comment: This worked fine for me in a `bash` script: `export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=${HOME}/ansible_1.log; ansible -m ping Client1; export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=${HOME}/ansible_2.log; ansible -m ping Client2`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "ansible environment", at least not in the way you describe it.

Usually nothing is persisted between different runs, but fact caching may, still depends on how you configure it.

If you want to persist data between runs you will have to DIY, either by using fact caching or by even generating vars files and loading them dynamically.

You can avoid adding load vars at start of the playbook by using `--extra-vars "@some_file.json"` when you call ansible. Still, if you will have to add a dump task at the end of the playbook.

Comment: Did you mean no matter what I do as you suggested, Ansible would not recognize it to determine a new log file pathname, and I'll have to rely on "custom" logging system (dump task)?